# How to automatically grant nodes chef_vault access in a recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife, cookbook, recipe

I have a recipe that requires credentials from chef_vault.

I would like to be able to merely apply this recipe (or even a role if necessary) to a node and have that node automatically added to the vault item's  client list the next time it does a chef run (when the recipe executes) so it can retrieve those creds. Is this possible?

I was thinking about having the recipe tag the node then run knife vault update from the recipe, but even if that works its a bit ugly.

Is there an elegant solution for this that doesn't require me to manually do anything and have the recipes that need vault creds assign them for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this (safely), it violates the security model and whole point of using an asymmetric pre-encryption system like chef-vault.

Comment: How does it violate the encryption system exactly I'm confused. Because any node you apply the recipe to has access and that's the security risk?

Comment: I've got 30 minutes of me talking about these things up at https://coderanger.net/talks/secrets/ but the tl;dw is that the thing generating the asym-crypted copies needs access to the secret in the clear, usually done in-band by a human having decryption access via the `-A` option on the vault. Due to Chef's security model, use of the `-S` flag with vault is unsafe at this time (see the start of https://coderanger.net/chef-and-vault/ even though that's about a different tool). You _could_ give one server access to every vault and run `knife vault refresh` from cron, but doing so is very risky.

Comment: chef-vault is absolutely the worst secrets system i have used. it requires manual work in what is supposed to be an automated configuration management system. my absolute favorite is chefs response: 'use hashicorp vault'.